# inheritance from xmlrpclib.ServerProxy in python

Tags: python

Why this code doesn't work ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
from xmlrpclib import ServerProxy
class ServerProxy1(ServerProxy):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__host)


proxy = ServerProxy1("http://workshop:58846/")
print proxy
```

Original_*str*_:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            "" %
            (self.__host, self.__handler)
            )

    __str__ = __repr__
```

Result:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpclib.Fault: :method "_ServerProxy1__host.__str__" is not supported'>
```

Comment: """ doesn't work" means what exactly?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is hiding in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python)

The member `self.__host` in class `ServerProxy` was declared using the double-underscore naming that's meant to indicate that it shouldn't be accessed by derived classes. To do this, the interpreter mangles its name internally in the form `_className__memberName` -- Python isn't C++, and treats that 'private' notation as a strong hint, not as an absolute prohibition.

When code is written with the double underscore prefix, you can access it like

```
class ServerProxy1(ServerProxy):
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._ServerProxy__host)
```

..but you shouldn't be surprised if a future version of the `ServerProxy` class changes its internal implementation and breaks your code.

Comment: Double-underscore name obfuscation for the loss! It's really the only feature about Python I truly hate. Further reading here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables